# Build second executable separately

Tags: cmake

I have a C++ project that uses CMake as the build system. To summarize, it has a single `CMakeLists.txt` in the root of the project that configures some variables, sets up the main sources, and adds the main sources to the main executable; then, it proceeds to call `add_library` and `target_link_libraries` several times (for SDL2, GLAD, and JsonCPP). Next, it creates a second executable containing some of its own sources and some of the sources and libraries also used in the main executable. Although irrelevant to the question, this executable contains unit tests only.

While my current configuration does produce the wanted result, that being one executable with the project itself and a completely separate executable containing the unit tests, it still adds overhead to the build time. You see, both the main executable and the second executable are always built whenever I call `make`. What I'd like is for `make` to only build the main executable, and for `make test` (or `make tests`, or `make catch`) to build the second executable.

I've tried a few methods but have for some reason been unsuccessful, and my searches across the internet have brought little results. I have a feeling that the answer lays within `add_custom_command`, and that I've simply been unable to understand it properly.

Answer (score 2):

You should also make sure that the unit test target and the main target are not already linked with a dependency (e.g. an `add_dependencies` command). Of course, if the 2 targets share a source file (which they shouldn't!) then there's not much that can be done without extensive refactoring.

You can use the [`EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html) target property on the second unit test target. However, having separate sources (as pointed out earlier) would avoid unnecessary rebuilds of the unit tests when the main source files are changed.

Furthermore, for calling that target with a custom name (if changing the name of the executable is not desirable), you can add an empty custom target and then add dependencies on it from the desired actual targets like this:

```
add_custom_target(tests)

# various other unit test targets
add_executable(FooUnitTest [...])

add_dependencies(tests FooUnitTest)
```

This will allow you to type `make tests` and build all the out-of-date targets the fake target is dependent upon.

Comment: Although this did solve my issue, I'd like to add a note regarding your first point. There were no previous add_dependencies, however, I still had to EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL because they share some source files. What I don't understand is why they shouldn't. The unit tests must be able to access the libraries used in the source code and the source headers themselves to perform tests, resulting in shared code. I'd also like to note that I ended up just changing the name of the executable - I hadn't realized I could build specific executables separately.

Comment: @octacian unit tests as proper clients they should use the headers and *link* against the library as any other potential user; this is mostly a clean design advice. I'd strive towards this. The EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL can work regardless, but if had separate sources (not headers), a change in them wouldn't trigger a rebuild of the unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

A plain `make` implicitly calls `make all`. So if you want to build a single target, you have to call it explicitly via `make <target>`.

To list all targets generated by CMake, call `make help`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two executables without compiling your sources two times with [object libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) in cmake.

```
add_library( common_objects OBJECT ${MY_SOURCES})

add_executable(exec1 $<TARGET_OBJECTS:common_objects> ${SOURCES_ONLY_FOR_FIRST})

# different configuration may be set
add_executable(exec2 $<TARGET_OBJECTS:common_objects> ${SOURCES_ONLY_FOR_SECOND})
```